# ExtJS 4 Check if class exists

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have array of names

```
 var names = ['X', 'Y']
```

For each name i want to create class instance but only if proper js file exists otherwise function should return null

```
    getTool:function(name) {

        var t = Ext.create('VC.tools.' + name + 'Tool',{
            map:this.map
        });

        return t.getEntryPoint();
}
```

Or maybe is there a way of implementing some kind of try catch? I just dont want any errors like file could not be loaded etc.

EDIT:

If i add try catch i can avoid is not a constructor error. But still got file not exists error. Is there a way of handling this?

```
    try {
                var t = Ext.create('VC.tools.' + name + 'Tool',{
                    map:this.map
                });

                return t.getEntryPoint();

            }catch(err){
                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the isCreated method on ClassManager: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ClassManager-method-isCreated

Comment: I have dynamic class loading. So i think i cannot use this method. The class should be loaded when i instantiate it

Answer (score 2):

You probably already found a solution, but just in case it could be helpful for someone else, you could use this:

```
if(Ext.ClassManager.getAliasesByName('[Classname to check]').length > 0) {

    // create the requested component
    var component = Ext.create('[Classname to check]');

    // add replace the contents of the center container with the created component
    centerContainer.removeAll();
    centerContainer.add(component);

} else {
    console.log('Uknown component: '+ '[Classname to check]');
}
```

It will not give you an error and will not try to download your classfile, if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the class I want to find didn't have an alias defined.  I found that I could use this:

```
function createClassIfExists(name) {
    var newClass;

    if(!Ext.isEmpty(Ext.ClassManager.getNamesByExpression(name + '*')))
        newClass = Ext.create(name);

    return newClass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the *'Ext.ClassManager'* be aware of a caveat to finding if a Class exists or not.   This code below will only work if your code has the Class you are looking for in the 'requires' section of the View code.

```
if(Ext.ClassManager.get('MyApp.view.Main'))
```

It will return *undefined* if it has not been added.

```
requires: [ 'MyApp.view.Main']
```

You can also add this to your App.js within the '*views'* section too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function openView(cid) {
    shortName = cid.substr(cid.lastIndexOf(".")+1, cid.length);
    if(Ext.get(shortName) == null) Ext.create(cid);
   Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp(shortName));
}
```

This function opens a view like

```
openView('MyApp.view.Oeffnungszeiten');
```

and if the View exists it accesses the old instance